# Create CNPostalAddress from known values

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, cnpostaladdress

I am trying to create a `CNPostalAddress` with some strings in Objective-C. I have street address, city, state, zip and country values. I have tried the code below but it’s not working. Thanks for your valuable time.

```
CNPostalAddress *postalAddr = [[CNPostalAddress alloc] init];
postalAddr.street = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",street1,street2];// here, I am getting an error: Street property is read only.
```

Answer (score 29):

Create a [CNMutablePostalAddress](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/CNMutablePostalAddress_Class/) instead of a CNPostalAddress:

```objc
CNMutablePostalAddress *postalAddr = [[CNMutablePostalAddress alloc] init];
postalAddr.street = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", street1, street2];
```

CNMutablePostalAddress is a subclass of CNPostalAddress, so you can use it like a CNPostalAddress from this point onward.

Answer (score 6):

The above answer rewritten in Swift:

```
let postalAddr = CNMutablePostalAddress()
postalAddr.street = String(format: "%@ %@", street1, street2)
```